# Como incrementar el valor de una variable con evento click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Mi problema es que tengo una variable a la cual necesito incrementar su valor con cada click, pero en mi código, esta no incrementa sino permanece con el mismo valor... Llego a la conclusión de que lo reconoce como un solo evento por lo que no actualiza el valor de la variable, mas sin embargo ya intente con `e.stopPropagation()` y otros métodos. A continuación intentare reproducir el error:

```js
$(".zoomContainner button").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var action = $(this).attr("class");
    var zoomSelectorCount = 0;
    var zoomSelector = {

        0: 0,
        1: 25,
        2: 50,
        3: 75,
        4: 100

    }

    if (action == "zoomIn") {
      zoomSelectorCount++;
      console.log(zoomSelectorCount);
    }else if (action == "zoomOut") {
      zoomSelectorCount--;
      console.log(zoomSelectorCount);
    }
  });
```

```css
* {

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

}

body {

  height: 300px;

}
.zoomContainner {

  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;

}

.zoomTool {

  background-color: #212121c2!important;
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: inline-block;

}

.zoomTool button {

  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: .2s;
  cursor: pointer;

}

.zoomTool button:hover {

  background-color: rgba(209, 209, 209, 0.53);

}

.zoomTool button i {

  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;

}

.zoomReset {

  margin: 0 1px;

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="zoomContainner">
          <div class="zoomTool">
            <button class="zoomOut" type="button" name="button"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></button>
            <button class="zoomReset" type="button" name="button"><i class="fas fa-search-minus"></i></button>
            <button class="zoomIn" type="button" name="button"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Me encuentro que al ejecutar el código, cuando disminuyo el valor de la variable esta resulta en **-1** y cuando la incremento retorna **1**.

¿Hay otra lógica que pueda seguir para llegar al resultado deseado? Gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que estas declarando el contador dentro del evento. Entonces siempre lo reinicia. Te agregue una validación para que no desborde el contador.

```js
 var zoomSelectorCount = 0;
$(".zoomContainner button").click(function(e) {

    var action = $(this).attr("class");
   
    var zoomSelector = {

        0: 0,
        1: 25,
        2: 50,
        3: 75,
        4: 100

    }

    if (action == "zoomIn" && zoomSelectorCount <4) {
      zoomSelectorCount++;
      console.log(zoomSelectorCount);
    }else if (action == "zoomOut" && zoomSelectorCount > 0) {
      zoomSelectorCount--;
      console.log(zoomSelectorCount);
    }
  });
```

```css
.zoomTool {

  background-color: #212121c2!important;
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: inline-block;

}

.zoomTool button {

  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: .2s;
  cursor: pointer;

}

.zoomTool button:hover {

  background-color: rgba(209, 209, 209, 0.53);

}

.zoomTool button i {

  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;

}

.zoomReset {

  margin: 0 1px;

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="zoomContainner">
          <div class="zoomTool">
            <button class="zoomOut" type="button" name="button"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></button>
            <button class="zoomReset" type="button" name="button"><i class="fas fa-search-minus"></i></button>
            <button class="zoomIn" type="button" name="button"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Espero que sea lo que necesitabas. Saludos!

Comment: Oye muy buena!!! No se como se me paso y gracias por la validación!

Comment: De nada! Saludos.

Comment: gracias crack , estaba busando la forma y no daba con la solcucion y no pense en que al dar cada click en el vento se reinicia todo